# Что такое очередь проверок и как она работает?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Вверху страницы я вижу ссылку «очередь проверок», нажав на которую, я попадаю на страницу со списком «очередей».

- Что такое очередь проверок?
- Для чего нужны различные очереди?
- Что я могу сделать с каждой из очередей?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Что такое очередь проверок?

Очереди проверки (или задачи проверки) содержат сообщения, которые, возможно, требуют внимания сообщества по мнению системы или других участников. Такие сообщения будут представлены вам по одному. В системе предусмотрены знаки за проверку, по аналогии с тревогами ([«Страж»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/custodian), [«Инспектор»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/78/reviewer), [«Завхоз»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)).

То, что понимается под «проверкой», зависит от типа конкретной очереди. Вне зависимости от типа, все очереди имеют одну общую черту – возможность «пропустить» сообщение. Пропустив сообщение, вы больше никогда не встретите его в очереди. Это полезно, если вы не уверены в том, какое действие следует предпринять.

Каждый участник имеет свои собственные копии очередей. Если вы просматриваете сообщение, оно не обязательно отсутствует в очереди других участников. Сообщение удалиться из всех очередей лишь после того, как несколько участников посмотрят его (точное число зависит от типа очереди и от конкретных действий участников).

## Зачем нужны разные очереди и что я могу делать с каждой из них?

Каждая очередь дает возможность участникам исследовать один определенный аспект сайта, позволяя участвовать в модерации сообщества несколькими способами.

### Запоздалые ответы и первые сообщения

Очередь запоздалых ответов содержит ответы, которые были опубликованы намного позже чем сами вопросы, и, как результат, могут не получить необходимого внимания со стороны сообщества. Цель этой очереди – привлечь к ним внимание.

Очередь первых сообщений содержит несколько сообщений, опубликованных новым участником, которому, вероятно, может потребоваться помощь в понимании правил работы сайта.

В этих двух очередях вы можете редактировать сообщения, отмечать их тревогой, голосовать, добавлять новые комментарии и голосовать за существующие. Когда вы совершаете какое–либо из этих действий, становится доступна кнопка «Готово», позволяющая завершить проверку. Если вы считаете, что сообщение не требует действий с вашей стороны, вы можете нажать кнопку «Действия не требуются». Если вы не уверены в том, что следует сделать с сообщением, пожалуйста, используйте кнопку «Пропустить».

Вы получите доступ к этим очередям, [когда ваша репутация достигнет 500 баллов](/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

**Примечание:** Данные очереди отсутствуют на метах (MSO требования по рейтингу выше).

### Сообщения низкого качества

Очередь сообщений низкого качества содержит сообщения, которые были автоматически определены как низкокачественные на основе различных системных критериев, с помощью которых рассчитывается показатель качества сообщения. В этой очереди также содержатся сообщения, которые были [*отмечены тревогой*](/help/privileges/flag-posts) за крайне низкое качество содержимого, а также ответы, отмеченные тревогой как [неприемлемые](/help/deleted-answers). Если вы считаете, что сообщение является приемлемым для сайта и при этом не может быть улучшено, нажмите кнопку **Выглядит нормально**. Помните, что вы можете оставить комментарий к сообщению до того, как нажать эту кнопку.

Если вы считаете, что сообщение является приемлемым, однако содержит ошибки форматирования или грамматические ошибки, вы можете нажать кнопку **Править** для того, чтобы исправить сообщение, причем после завершения правки эта кнопка превращается в кнопку **Выглядит нормально**.

Если сообщение нельзя «спасти», существует два варианта дальнейших действий в зависимости от того, является сообщение вопросом или ответом:

- кнопка **Закрыть** для вопросов. Открывает меню, позволяющее выбрать описание причины закрытия вопроса. Если у вас нет [привилегий для закрытия вопросов](/help/privileges/close-questions), вместо этой кнопки вам будет предложена кнопка **Рекомендовать закрыть** – сама по себе она не приводит к закрытию, но добавляет вопрос в соответствующую очередь.
- кнопка **Удалить** для ответов. Открывает меню, предлагающее выбрать один из шаблонных комментариев. Выбирать комментарий не обязательно, но если в списке имеется комментарий, подходящий к ситуации, будет вежливо по отношению к автору удаляемого сообщения, добавить комментарий, поясняющий причину принятого вами решения. Выбранный комментарий автоматически добавляется к ответу от вашего имени (если до этого не был добавлен аналогичный же комментарий). Если у вас нет привилегии «[Проверенный участник](/help/privileges/trusted-user)», вместо этой кнопки вам будет предложена кнопка **Рекомендовать удаление** – она установит приоритет для задания на проверку для других участников, которые *могут* голосовать за удаление, и, если достаточное количество участников рекомендуют удаление сообщения, сообщение может быть удалено (если рейтинг ниже или равен 0), либо оно попадет к модераторам для последующей проверки.

Доступ к этой очереди появляется с [возможностью редактировать вопросы и ответы](/privileges/edit).

### Голоса за закрытие/повторное открытие

В этих очередях находятся вопросы, которые, возможно, требуют закрытия или повторного открытия. Вопросы, имеющие действующие голоса за закрытие или отмеченные тревогой как требующие закрытия, отображаются в очереди на закрытие, а вопросы, имеющие действующие голоса за повторное открытие, а также вопросы, которые были отредактированы после закрытия, появляются в очереди на повторное открытие. Наряду с инструментами модератора, очередь на закрытие является одним из лучших способов нахождения сообщений, которые требуют закрытия.

В этих очередях существуют четыре допустимых варианта действий. Можно попробовать исправить вопрос в очереди на закрытия, с помощью кнопки **Править**. После правки, вопрос автоматически будет убран из очереди. Можно проголосовать за закрытие вопроса (в очереди на повторное открытие соответствующим вариантом действий будет являться голос за повторное открытие). Если вы не уверены в том, должно ли сообщение быть закрыто либо повторно открыто, вы можете и должны «**Пропустить**» его, чтобы дать возможность другим участникам проверить сообщение. Наконец, можно использовать кнопку **Оставить открытым** (либо **Оставить закрытым** в очереди на повторное открытие). Если достаточное количество человек голосует за то, чтобы оставить вопрос открытым или закрытым, такой вопрос удаляется из очереди на закрытие/повторное открытие, что незамедлительно приводит к началу «устаревания» имеющихся голосов за закрытие или повторное открытие (но *не* удаляет их).

Доступ к этой очереди появляется с [возможностью отдавать голоса за закрытие и повторное открытие](/privileges/close-questions).

### Предложенные правки

В эту очередь попадают правки, внесенные участниками, не имеющими достаточно репутации для редактирования сообщений. Если два участника принимают правку, она применяется к сообщению. Если один участник отклоняет правку, а второй — принимает, система будет ждать, когда другие участники проверят правку. Отклоните правку, если вы считаете, что правка:

- **слишком незначительная**: минимум изменений, сообщение было хорошим и без редактирования;
- **вандализм**: правка сделала сообщение хуже;
- **полное изменение**: правка полностью изменила смысл исходного сообщения;
- **неверная**: вероятно, это должен был быть комментарий или ответ, а не правка;
- **плагиат**: правка представляет собой просто скопированную информацию из какого-либо внешнего источника без блока цитаты и ссылки на источник.

Если вы считаете необходимым внести дополнительные исправления в сообщения, используйте кнопку **Улучшить**. Примите решение отмечать ли правку как «полезную» (если правка не имеет такой опции, она автоматически отклоняется, но при этом добавляется в очередь улучшенная вами версия). Наличие слишком большого количества отклоненных правок приводит к временному запрету на добавление участником новых предложений; помните об этом, когда отклоняете правки.

Доступ к этой очереди появляется с [возможностью редактировать вопросы и ответы](/privileges/edit).

**Смотрите также:** [Как работают предложенные правки?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)