# Что делать с вопросами-дубликатами?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Что нужно сделать при обнаружении вопроса-дубликата?

- Ответить на вопрос?
- Проголосовать против?
- Оставить комментарий?
- Отредактировать вопрос и указать, что это дубликат?
- Закрыть вопрос или проголосовать за закрытие (при наличии соответствующих привилегий)?
- Что произойдёт, если я проголосую за закрытие вопроса как дубликата?
  Или: Почему на странице дубликата только что появился комментарий от моего имени?
- Нужно ли отметить такой вопрос тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора?
- А что насчёт похожих или связанных вопросов?

<sub>Свободный перевод статьи: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/</sub>

Answer (score 7):

> ### Коротко
>
> Если вопрос является дубликатом существующего вопроса, следует отметить вопрос тревогой или проголосовать за его закрытие.

### В каких случаях два вопроса считаются дубликатами?

По мнению Джоэл Спольски, следует [закрывать только очевидные дубликаты](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Джефф Этвуд выделяет [три категории дубликатов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/): дубликаты, созданные методом копирования и вставки; непреднамеренные дубликаты; сомнительные дубликаты (по которым решение принимает сообщество).

Вопросы могут считаться дубликатами, если на них получены (могут быть получены) **одинаковые ответы**. Сюда относятся не только дословные дубликаты, но также и вопросы, в которых одна и та же идея выражена разными словами.

Вопросы, посвящённые одинаковым аспектам одного и того же понятия, но с разными примерами, в одних случаях могут быть дубликатами, а в других — нет, в зависимости от того, насколько легко один вопрос выводится из другого. Если различие между вопросами заключается только в числовых значениях или названиях переменных, вопросы считаются дубликатами. Если же взаимосвязь между вопросами требует подробного пояснения, вопросы являются связанными, а не дубликатами.

### Какой вопрос из двух считать дубликатом?

Чаще всего более поздний вопрос закрывается как дубликат вопроса, заданного ранее, но возможны исключения. Общее правило гласит: **следует сохранять вопрос с лучшим набором ответов** и закрывать другой как дубликат. Если вопрос остался без ответа, система не позволит вам выбрать его как источник дубликата (за исключением случаев, когда у обоих вопросов один автор).

Если на один из вопросов получены качественные ответы, но сам вопрос плохо сформулирован, а у другого вопроса хорошая формулировка, но при этом ответы низкого качества или их нет совсем, следует отредактировать плохо сформулированный вопрос.

При возникновении сомнений закройте более поздний вопрос как дубликат.

### Вопрос точно является дубликатом. Что следует сделать?

Если вы обладаете привилегией [голосовать за закрытие вопроса](/help/privileges/close-questions), нажмите ссылку «закрыть», выберите пункт «этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение…» и добавьте ссылку на исходный вопрос.

Если у вас нет привилегии голосовать за закрытие вопроса, но вы можете [оставлять комментарии](/help/privileges/comment) (для этого требуется 50 баллов репутации), нажмите кнопку «Тревога», выберите пункт «Дубликат...» и добавьте ссылку на исходный вопрос.

Если вы первым отмечаете вопрос дубликатом, под вопросом [автоматически появится комментарий](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate), в котором будет указан источник дубликата.

#### Следует ли редактировать вопрос?

Не нужно специально редактировать дублирующий вопрос, так как информация о том, что это дубликат, будет добавлена автоматически при закрытии вопроса.

#### Нужно ли отвечать на вопрос?

Нет, если вы считаете, что это дубликат. Если вас не устраивают ответы на источник вопроса-дубликата, предложите свой вариант.

Если вы не считаете вопрос дубликатом, то, безусловно, на него нужно ответить.

#### Нужно ли оставлять комментарий?

Когда кто-либо из участников сообщества голосует за закрытие вопроса как дубликата, комментарий добавляется автоматически. Добавлять ещё один комментарий имеет смысл только в том случае, если вы хотите дополнить информацию.

#### Нужно ли отмечать вопрос тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора?

Нет. Отмечайте вопрос тревогой как дубликат, только если вы не можете проголосовать за закрытие вопроса. Вопрос следует отмечать тревогой в следующих случаях:

- **Нарушение правил**: если участник задаёт один и тот же вопрос снова и снова, отметьте сообщение тревогой и сообщите модераторам. В обращении к модераторам укажите ссылки на все соответствующие вопросы.
- **Объединение вопросов**: модераторы могут объединить вопросы-дубликаты, при этом все ответы будут перенесены в один вопрос. Объединение возможно только в том случае, если вопросы имеют идентичные или очень похожие формулировки. Если вы считаете, что два вопроса нужно объединить, проверьте, подойдут ли ответы в текущей формулировке к объединяемому вопросу. В этом случае отметьте дубликат тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора (независимо от того, был ли вопрос уже закрыт), укажите ссылку на второй вопрос и поясните, почему вы считаете, что вопросы следует объединить.
- Дубликаты вопросов **без ответа**: рядовые участники не могут закрыть вопрос как дубликат существующего, если на него не было получено ни одного ответа. Отмечая такие сообщения тревогой, вы помогаете выявить вопросы, оставшиеся без ответа. При этом, даже если для конкретных условий вопроса А возможен ответ, который не подойдёт для вопроса Б, ваши действия дополнительно снижают риск того, что вопрос А будет закрыт как дубликат вопроса Б. Если вы уверены, что два вопроса без ответа являются дубликатами, отметьте один из них тревогой для привлечения внимания модератора и поясните причину.

#### Нужно ли голосовать против вопроса?

Здесь нет однозначного ответа. Наличие вопросов-дубликатов — это необязательно плохо: различные описания аналогичной проблемы помогут будущим посетителям найти нужные ответы.  И всё же, если вы задаёте вопрос, являющийся дубликатом существующего, это может указывать на недостаточную предварительную подготовку, что само по себе является основанием для голосования против вашего вопроса.

### Что происходит с вопросами-дубликатами?

Вопрос [закрывается](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work) как дубликат, если пять человек, обладающих привилегией голосовать за закрытие вопроса, или участник, задавший вопрос, признают вопрос дубликатом либо если участник с соответствующими привилегиями проголосует за закрытие такого вопроса. После этого вопрос останется на сайте, но участники могут добавлять новые ответы только к источнику дубликата.

На страницу вопроса–дубликата будет добавлена специальная рамка со ссылкой на источник (или источники, если их несколько). При этом если на вопрос не опубликовано ни одного ответа, то анонимные посетители сайта будут автоматически перенаправлены на источник дубликата.

### Нужно ли удалять дубликаты?

В большинстве случаев нет: основная часть дубликатов сохраняется на сайте. Поскольку посетители сайта по-разному формулируют вопрос при поиске, наличие нескольких вариантов вопроса, выраженных различными словами, поможет им найти нужные ответы.

Участники, обладающие соответствующими привилегиями, могут удалять дословные копии других вопросов или дубликаты, настолько плохо сформулированные, что они не приносят пользы сообществу.

### Если я не согласен с тем, что вопрос отметили как дубликат...

Вопросы могут быть похожими, но при этом не являться полными дубликатами:

[Цитаты из блога](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/):

> По одной и той же теме возможны сотни различных, связанных и полностью соответствующих требованиям вопросов. Не существует такого понятия, как «единственно правильный вопрос».

и...

> Редко когда все настолько очевидно — обычно вам могут встретиться два похожих, но при этом не полностью одинаковых вопроса, каждый из которых обладает ценностью по разным причинам.

Если вы считаете, что вопросы связаны, но не являются дубликатами, следует отредактировать вопрос и пояснить, в чём заключается отличие. Можно использовать следующую формулировку:

> В отличие от вопроса [«Какого цвета небо на Титане?»](link), меня интересует планета, вращающаяся вокруг коричневого карлика.

Если вопрос появился в [очереди проверок в связи с голосованием за закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4912/), вы можете проголосовать за то, чтобы оставить вопрос открытым. Если вопрос закрыт, а вы обладаете привилегиями [голосовать за закрытие](/help/privileges/close-questions), вы также можете проголосовать за повторное открытие вопроса.

Comment: *Если вопрос остался без ответа, система не позволит вам выбрать его как источник дубликата* — позволит, если у обоих вопросов один автор.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо, поправил! Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь вносить уточнения самостоятельно!