# Заменить ссылку на пост про очередь проверок в статье про закрытые вопросы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, закрытие-вопросов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас ссылка ведёт на [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

Нужно заменить на ссылку на наш перевод: [Что такое очередь проверок и как она работает?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4912/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Внес необходимые изменения.

Comment: А рядовые модераторы не имеют доступа к правке этих страниц? И, кстати, из ссылки хорошо бы убрать id участника. И ещё, почему Вы не голосуете, если вопрос был действительно полезный?

Comment: @älёxölüt как я понял, им на конкретные страницы выдаётся доступ.

Comment: @Suvitruf я слышал вроде, что можно до трёх страниц одновременно на редактирование открыть. Но хз как там этот механизм работает. Может на MSE порыться или задать вопрос даже. Но пока что-то лень :)

Comment: @älёxölüt я в офисе пока. Вечером подумаю над этим)