# Удалить идентификатор участника из ссылок в справочных страницах

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка, ссылки, идентификатор-участника

При недавних заменах в справочных страницах ссылок на англоязычные публикации (блог SO или сообщения на MSE) ссылками на их русскоязычные аналоги (в основном сообщения на ruSO Мете) [было замечено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8541/8545#comment35285_8545), что некоторые ссылки содержат идентификатор участника, который эту ссылку предоставил. Ссылки, полученные через пункт "поделиться" содержат такой id:

> [image: пример ссылки]

Использование идентификаторов участников в подобных ссылках в справочном центре я считаю неуместным. К тому же это может способствовать, как мне кажется, незаслуженному получению участником знаков типа [Диктор](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Усилитель](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster) и [Публицист](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist).

Для доступа к самой упоминаемой странице идентификатор участника не нужен.

Comment: Ух, что-то не подумал об этом. Поменяю в вопросе как дома буду.

Comment: А мне публициста яндекс подарил)))

Comment: @Qwertiy а мне сплиттер для наушников и шариковую ручку.

Comment: @Suvitruf никто уже не знает, что для вас является домом :)

Comment: @älёxölüt, что-то я связь не уловил...

Comment: @Qwertiy подсказка "яндекс"

Comment: На мой взгляд, слова про «незаслуженные знаки» незаслуженные, потому что на размещение ссылки на каком–нибудь другом сайте уходит ровно столько же, если не меньше, времени (все–таки тут речь о переводах идет!) С другой стороны, согласен, в справке, вероятно, лучше иметь ссылки без идентификаторов, например, чтобы не было «войны» правок, хотя они очень мало вероятны.

Comment: @älёxölüt, а с вопросом?)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну войны правок в справке быть не может, потому что участники её редактировать не могут. Но справку читает куча народу, так что действительно похоже на необоснованную накрутку для знаков (если они считаются, а то внутрисайнтовые переходы вроде не учитываются в знаках). А вот в списках типа литературы я бы оставил реферральные - кто добавил - того и ссылка.

Comment: @Qwertiy *"а с вопросом?)"* ← это о чём?

Comment: @älёxölüt, про улавливание связи.

Comment: @Qwertiy с вопросом связь через комментарий.

Comment: @älёxölüt поправил ссылку в своих вопросах)

Answer (score 3):

Да, в разделах справки данный идентификатор не нужен.

Я считаю, что участник при публикации вопросов, в которых предполагается правка справочных разделов должен убирать этот идентификатор. (Да я понимаю, что это немного нудная операция - и обычно её никто не делает, но тут это важно)

А если автор по незнанию или недоразумению допустит подобную ошибку - то её может исправить как любой заметивший эту ошибку участник (можно в комментариях к правке или под вопросом оставить ссылку на эту тему с разъяснениями).

Ну и перед публикацией на офсайт сотрудник компании или модератор имеющий соответствующий уровень доступа должен ещё раз перепроверить ссылки и по необходимости вырезать этот id из ссылок.

PS Я точно не уверен, будут ли засчитываться переходы для получения знаков Диктор/Усилитель/Публицист. Дело в том, что в некоторых случаях подобные переходы не засчитываются, я где-то видел об этом упоминания, но точно не скажу где.

Comment: ЕМНИП, учитываются переходы только со сторонних (не относящихся к Stack Exchange) сайтов

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а по-моему, со всех сайтов кроме двух своих - основного и его меты.

Comment: @AK, про справку согласен, а вот про другие вопросы со справочными материалами не согласен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov про знаки не могу точно сказать, но на каком-то из предыдущих winter-bash получил шапку за ссылку в чате. Механизм, я думаю, там одинаковый, что для шапок, что для знаков. Хотя это только догадки.